# Is it possible to enable Official Tailwind Plugins?

Tags: tailwind-css, astrojs

**How to enable Official Tailwind Plugins while using `astrojs/tailwind`?**

I have installed the typography plugin, restarted the server, and refreshed the browser. But I still have a small H1 heading.

- `npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography`  ➡
- Then I've added  `require('@tailwindcss/typography')` to my `tailwind.config.js`

My package.json is ...

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^0.2.5",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.4",
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `@astro/tailwind` with **official tailwind plugins** is possible.

My mistake was to use *H1* tags without *prose* class.

I did not use a top div with prose class. After adding `prose` class it worked.

```
        <div class="prose prose-slate mx-auto">
          <h1>Your Header</h1>
        </div>
```